# Formatting datetime in Excel

Tags: datetime, excel-formula

I'm doing a data analytics course and we're learning the LEN, FIND, LEFT & RIGHT functions. The instructor is using Google Sheets, and with the datetime format being "yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss" Using the =LEN function, they returned 19 characters. When I did in excel, it only returned 15. When they used the =FIND(" ", C2), it returned 11, when I used the same function, it returned a #VALUE error and won't connect to the server to tell me why.

I clicked on cell C2, and it showed my datetime being set up as yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss AM - though I couldn't see the AM in my actual cell.

I assumed for the =LEN function, it wasn't counting the colons, but I can't figure out why it wouldn't calculate the =FIND(" ", C2). When I noticed the "AM" in it, I tried deleting it, but had the same #VALUE error. I also tried re-formatting the datetime, but then would end up with only the date or the time and not both.

Comment: IF you use "FIND(" ", C2)" then it returns the position of the first space, which is position 11. Confusing to many, but just remember a space " " is just a character like a, b or c...

Comment: Date/datetime is stored as a number / fractional number, so searching for a space in the number returns an error. I think the course works with strings (text, not the value formatted as date). Excel converts a date or date including time to a value by default when formatted as general. You could start off typing a `'` to tell Excel what you type is a string, followed by your date text. But I don't know if that's the case here.

Comment: And generally Google sheets and Excel may share some similarities, they are not the same. And why not direct these questions to the instructor? (And ask him to show solutions using Excel instead maybe?)